# How can I remove all my changes in my SVN working directory?

Tags: svn

I have an SVN working directory. I made some changes in that directory, and it shows in [`svn status`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.status.html). But is there any way for me to remove all my changes in there and just get everything from the trunk using the command line?

Answer (score 305):

```
svn revert -R .
svn up
```

This will recursively revert the current directory and everything under it and then update to the latest version.

Comment: Note that this does not work with externals (they are ignored, seemingly).

Answer (score 91):

I used a combination of other peoples' answers to come up with this solution:

### Revert normal local SVN changes

```
svn revert -R .
```

#### Remove any other change and supports removing files/folders with spaces, etc.

```
svn status --no-ignore | \
  grep -E '(^\?)|(^\I)' | \
  sed -e 's/^. *//' | \
  sed -e 's/\(.*\)/"\1"/' | \
  xargs rm -rf
```

### Don't forget to get the latest files from SVN

```
svn update --force
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Shaize, this is the most elegant sed, ... pipe I've seen so far for this :) Especially taking care about the ignores also.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 38):

```
svn revert -R .
svn cleanup . --remove-unversioned
```

Comment: It does not remove *.class files etc.

Comment: if you also want to remove ignored files- `svn cleanup . --remove-ignored`

Answer (score 14):

If you have no changes, you can always be really thorough and/or lazy and do...

```
rm -rf *
svn update
```

But, no really, do **not** do that unless you are **really sure** that the nuke-from-space option is what you want!!  This has the advantage of also nuking all build cruft, temporary files, and things that SVN ignores.

The more correct solution is to use the revert command:

```
svn revert -R .
```

The -R causes subversion to recurse and revert everything in and below the current working directory.

Comment: I often used this trick, but with SVN 1.7, where metadata is stored only in the WC root, this no longer is the clean solution it was. For instance, deleted files remain deleted.

Comment: `svn nuke-from-space`

Answer (score 9):

None of the answers here were quite what I wanted. Here's what I came up with:

```
# Recursively revert any locally-changed files
svn revert -R .

# Delete any other files in the sandbox (including ignored files),
# being careful to handle files with spaces in the name
svn status --no-ignore | grep '^\?' | \
    perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if $_ =~ /^\S+\s+(.*)$/' | \
    tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

Tested on Linux; may work in Cygwin, but relies on (I believe) a GNU-specific extension which allows xargs to split based on `'\0'` instead of whitespace.

The advantage to the above command is that it does not require any network activity to reset the sandbox. You get exactly what you had before, and you **lose all your changes**. (disclaimer before someone blames me for this code destroying their work) ;-)

I use this script on a continuous integration system where I want to make sure a clean build is performed after running some tests.

**Edit**: I'm not sure this works with all versions of Subversion. It's not clear if the `svn status` command is always formatted consistently. Use at your own risk, as with any command that uses such a blanket `rm` command.

Answer (score 7):

**svn revert** will undo any local changes you've made

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following command to revert all local changes:

```
svn st -q | awk '{print $2;}' | xargs svn revert
```

Comment: I get the error message "Not enough arguments" for svn revert

Answer (score 4):

```
svn status | grep '^M' | sed -e 's/^.//' | xargs rm

svn update
```

Will remove any file which has been modified.  I seem to remember having trouble with revert when files and directories may have been added.

Answer (score 1):

[svn revert](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re25.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows, the following for loop will revert all uncommitted changes made to your workspace:

```
for /F "tokens=1,*" %%d in ('svn st') do (
  svn revert "%%e"
)
```

If you want to remove all uncommitted changes and all unversioned objects, it will require 2 loops:

```
for /F "tokens=1,*" %%d in ('svn st') do (
  svn revert "%%e"
)
for /F "tokens=1,*" %%d in ('svn st') do (
  svn rm --force "%%e"
)
```